# Set multiple outlook categories

Tags: vbscript, outlook, categories

I'm attempting to work with Outlook using VBScript to change the categories on an email based on certain criteria. My problem is I can't figure out how VBScript handles interacting with Outlook for assigning multiple categories.

```
Set objOutlook   = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMailbox   = objNamespace.Folders("team")
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox").Folders.Item("test")
Set colItems = objFolder.Items
mycount = objFolder.Items.Count

If objItem.Categories = "Purple Category" Then
    objItem.Categories = "Purple Category, Green Category"
```

But that isn't working. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: How *exactly* is it "not working"?

Comment: You don't create this object anywhere `objItem`. You didn't get an error message?

Comment: It doesn't set the category, that's how it's not working. and no it's not getting an error message, I'm not sure strict so I don't need it created.

Answer (score 1):

The categories must be separated with ";". You also need to save the item:

```
If objItem.Categories = "Purple Category" Then
    objItem.Categories = "Purple Category;Green Category"
    objItem.Save
End If
```