# How to apply multiple categories based on each file type of attachments?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am automating email filing.

When, for example, a ".dwg" file is found first and a ".jpg" is attached as well, it only categorizes my email by "Native Files" and doesn't also categorize it as "Photos".

```vb
Sub Categorize_Emails(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    'Check each attachment
    For Each olkAtt In item.Attachments
        'If the attachments file name ends with .dwg
        If Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".dwg" Then
            'Categorize email
            item.Categories = "Native Files"
            item.Save

        'If the attachments file name ends with .dxf
        ElseIf Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".dxf" Then
            'Categorize email
            item.Categories = "Native Files"
            item.Save
                        
        'If the attachments file name ends with .jpg
        ElseIf Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".jpg" Then
            'Categorize email
            item.Categories = "Photos"
            item.Save
            
        'If the attachments file name ends with .xlsx
        ElseIf Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            'Categorize email
            item.Categories = "Native Files"
            item.Save
        
        ElseIf InStr(0, LCase(olkAtt.FileName), "RFI") <> 0 Then
            'Categorize email
            item.Categories = "RFI/DCN/FCN"
            item.Save
            
            End If
    Exit For
    Next
    Set olkAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

I thought this would look at each attachment, run through the if statements and then categorize the email per attachment. I want emails to have multiple categories if there are multiple cases of files.

After some help from Tim, here's the updated code:

```vb
Sub Categorize_Emails(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment, attName As String
    'Check each attachment
    For Each olkAtt In item.Attachments
    
    attName = LCase(olkAtt.FileName)
        'If the attachment is an RFI or DCN or FCN
        If InStr(LCase(attName), "rfi") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(attName), "dcn") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(attName), "fcn") <> 0 Then
            'Categorize email
            AddCategory item, "RFI/DCN/FCN"
        
        'If the attachments file name ends with .jpg
        ElseIf Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".jpg" Then
            'Categorize email
            AddCategory item, "Photos"
            
        'If the attachments file name ends with .dwg or .dxf or .xlsx
        ElseIf Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".dwg" Or Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".dxf" Or Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            'Categorize email
            AddCategory item, "Native Files"
                        
        End If
    
    Next olkAtt
    Set olkAtt = Nothing
End Sub


'add a category to an item if it doesn't already exist
Sub AddCategory(itm, cat)
    Const SEP As String = ";"
    Dim c, bExists As Boolean
    If Len(itm.Categories) = 0 Then
        itm.Categories = cat
        itm.Save
    Else
        arr = Split(itm.Categories, SEP)
        For Each c In arr
            If c = cat Then
                bExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        If Not bExists Then
            itm.Categories = Join(arr, SEP) & SEP & cat 'add if not present
            itm.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The categories already exist so I shouldn't need to add a new one to the existing category list.

Comment: My bad - removed.  The answer though is that you need to append each new category to the previous one: "Categories is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character specified in the value name, sList, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories. To convert the string of category names to an array of category names, use the Microsoft Visual Basic function Split."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.categories

Comment: ok, so i'd need to return a string value after each check, then convert/append those strings into an array and then use `item.Categories = array` to get it to assign to each category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.categories

> Categories is a delimited string of category names that have been
>   assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character
>   specified in the value name, sList, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
>   Panel\International in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for
>   multiple categories. To convert the string of category names to an
>   array of category names, use the Microsoft Visual Basic function Split

So something like this (untested):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment, attName As String

    '...
    '...

    'Check each attachment
    For Each olkAtt In Item.Attachments

        attName = LCase(olkAtt.Filename)

        If Right(attName, 4) = ".dwg" Or Right(attName, 4) = ".dxf" Or _
           Right(attName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then

           AddCategory Item, "Native Files"
        ElseIf Right(attName, 4) = ".jpg" Then
            AddCategory Item, "Photos"
        ElseIf InStr(0, attName, "RFI") <> 0 Then
            AddCategory Item, "RFI/DCN/FCN"
        End If
        'Exit For  '???
    Next
    Set olkAtt = Nothing
End Sub

'add a category to an item if it doesn't already exist
Sub AddCategory(itm, cat)
    Const SEP As String = ","
    Dim c, bExists As Boolean
    If Len(itm.Categories) = 0 Then
        itm.Categories = cat
        itm.Save
    Else
        arr = Split(itm.Categories, SEP)
        For Each c In arr
            If c = cat Then
                bExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        If Not bExists Then
            itm.Categories = Join(arr, SEP) & SEP & cat 'add if not present
            itm.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So I incorp'd your code and it still isn't adding multiple categories to one email when there are multiple attachments that meet the criteria. I'll edit my OP with the new code jic I missed something in translation.

Comment: also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39781815/8478902, however changing the `SEP` to `;` seems to break the script when I test it

Comment: When I debug the code, it only looks at the first attachment and then doesn't iterate through the remaining.

Comment: Figured it out, my `for` statement had an error, I exited out before it would iterate through each attachment. Thanks!